# How to auto resize tableView which displays search results?

Tags: ios, swift, anchor

This is how I'm adding UITableView:

```
tableView = UITableView()
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
tableView.rowHeight = 60.0
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
view.addSubview(tableView)

tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

tableViewHeightAnchor = tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
let constraints = [tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor), tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor), tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor), tableViewHeightAnchor!]
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

Especially this part is important:

```
tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
```

before I've tried to connect it to the bottom part of my UISearchController's searchBar but in this case it was crashing.

and in my

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
    tableView.reloadData()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6) {
        self.tableViewHeightAnchor.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
    }
}
```

I was adjusting the height anchor and set it equal to the contentSize of the tableView.
but I have a problem:

When there are only 1-2 rows to display, I do not see my tableView at all!  I can see it only when I add +200.0 to the contentSize but this solution is very bad and difficult to control, as it was not displayed correctly in that case.

How can I fix that? It's my first time when I try to do all my design in code and it's really confusing sometimes. Maybe someone can explain me what goes wrong there

Answer (score 0):

Just subclass `UITableView` and override `intrinsicContentSize` property.

```
class IntrinsicTableView: UITableView {

    override var contentSize:CGSize {
        didSet {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's automatically adjust height of tableview, no manual  adjustment required.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using these constraints, which should auto resize it for you up until the height reaches the same height as the screen, then the tableview will allow scrolling.

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .greaterThanOrEqual, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **layoutIfNeeded()** after setting constant for height constraint.

If just want tableview looks like it is resized then set **Separator to none** and add a line inside the cell so tableView view looks like it is resized but it remains same as screen size.